# Removing white space in between elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just got in to web design, I know basic HTML and CSS and I am trying to create a standard home page just to increase my skills and knowledge.

I have created a standard nav bar and my next step is to create a hero box with an image underneath the nav bar. I am using a section tag to achieve this, however there is a gap between the nav bar and the section and I am not sure how to remove this. Below is the link, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="main-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <section>
            <div class="container">
                section 1
            </div>
        </section>
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25994/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:** Add a class `.nav-bar-custom` in navbar because you can use multiple navbar and use custom css againist this navbar's **main nav**. `ul.main-nav{margin-bottom:0px;}`

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.nav-bar-custom ul.main-nav{margin-bottom:0px;}
.main-nav li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

section{
  background-color: #808080;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-bar-custom">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="main-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<section>
    <div class="container">section 1</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers now have an inspect tool - to look at the element in question, see what CSS is effecting it, and what the box model - it's padding, size and positioning.

Looking at your fiddle, it's going to either be a property effecting the top of section, .container, or a property affecting the bottom of nav. For nav - given that the black background stops - it would be a margin and not padding if it is that. The inspector when hightlighting elements suggests it is the bottom of the nav.

It appears that there is a `.navbar` style effecting it - which has `margin-bottom: 20px`. If you remove this - you will no longer have a gap between the nav and your content. However, since it comes from the bootstrap min css - you'll need to override it.

You can add this after the bootstrap inclusion to do so:

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see it the first time. Thank you.